# Updating an array that is NULL to an empty array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, null

So I have problem where I want to filter things and then update them twice.

Say I have this table called `licence`:

```
licence_id | user_id |  property   |     validity_dates             |  competition_ids    |
-----------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------
         1 |      20 | JOHN        | [2022-01-01,2025-01-02)        | 
         2 |      21 | JOHN        | [2022-01-01,2025-01-02)        | {abcd-efg, asda-12df}
```

I'd like to update `competition_ids` which are `NULL` into an empty array such as `'{}'` because this script

```
ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(array_cat(competition_ids, ARRAY['hijk-23lm'] )))
```

works only on empty arrays instead of `NULL`s. Once I convert them into empty arrays, I'd like to use the same script again.

The script only works on empty arrays ( `'{}'` ) and not `NULL`s. If I can make the script work with `NULL` values, then this post is pretty much solved. But If I can't then this post is still a problem unfortunately.

The current script I'm using does not change `NULLS` into '{}' and I'm not sure exactly why.

```
UPDATE licence 
SET competition_ids =
  (CASE
    WHEN competition_ids is NULL 
    THEN ARRAY['{}'] THEN ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(array_cat(competition_ids, ARRAY['hijk-23lm'] )))
    ELSE ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(array_cat(competition_ids, ARRAY['hijk-23lm'] )))
  END)
WHERE NOT competition_ids  @> ARRAY['hijk-23lm']
AND validity_dates = DATERANGE('2022-01-01', '2025-01-02', '[)')
AND property = 'JOHN';
```

Comment: Ar you trying to append a value to the array?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes that's correct, however by default empty arrays are set into NULL, and therefore my script isn't appending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your script:

```sql
ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(array_cat(competition_ids, ARRAY['hijk-23lm'])))
```

has no problem with a `null` in the `competition_ids` field: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lSCqlcRM)

```sql
select ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(array_cat(null, ARRAY['hijk-23lm'])));
-- {hijk-23lm}
select ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(array_cat('{}', ARRAY['hijk-23lm'])));
-- {hijk-23lm}
```

The reason your `update` statement doesn't affect the first record is because `null @> text[]` results in a `null` so your `where` condition filters it out. The statement ends up skipping that row.

You can use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to fix it.

```sql
WHERE NOT coalesce(competition_ids,'{}'::text[]) @> ARRAY['hijk-23lm']
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/7ZJuKM9v):

```sql
UPDATE licence 
SET competition_ids 
= ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(array_cat(competition_ids, ARRAY['hijk-23lm'])))
WHERE NOT coalesce(competition_ids,'{}'::text[]) @> ARRAY['hijk-23lm']
AND validity_dates = DATERANGE('2022-01-01', '2025-01-02', '[)')
AND property = 'JOHN';
```

Comment: I wonder how Coalesce handled it internally in this case? It returns the first argument that is not NULL? However, for the case that competition_ids is NULL, how does it return the competition_ids?

Comment: Your guess is exactly what you'll find in the linked documentation: *"The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not null."*. You only need to use it in the `where` section because in your `SET` part, `array_cat()` handles null arguments on its own. [See this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/J-G1TTNe)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to unnest and aggregate the array. You can use the concatenation operator `||` to append a new element to an array. To deal with NULL values use `coalesce()`

```
UPDATE licence 
   SET competition_ids = coalesce(competition_ids, '{}')||'hijk-23lm'
WHERE NOT competition_ids  @> ARRAY['hijk-23lm']
AND validity_dates = DATERANGE('2022-01-01', '2025-01-02', '[)')
AND property = 'JOHN';
```

If you are dealing with arrays that possibly contain unique elements, the best approach is probably to create a function that handles this:

```
create function append_unique(p_one text[], p_other text[])
  returns text[]
as
$$
  select array(
     select *
     from unnest(coalesce(p_one, '{}')) 
     union 
     select *
     from unnest(coalesce(p_other, '{}'))
   );
$$   
language sql
immutable;
```

Then use it like this:

```
SET competition_ids = append_unique(competition_ids, ARRAY['hijk-23lm'])
```

---

A better solution might be to use a properly normalized data model with a one-to-many relationship where you can define a unique constraint that ensures this. Adding elements can then be done using `insert ... on conflict`

Comment: I've used unnest and aggregate to avoid duplication, although I think given your solution, I might just find a way to implement such.

Comment: Well as you used `NOT competition_ids  @> ARRAY['hijk-23lm']` in your WHERE clause, you will not add the string to an array that already contains it.

Comment: If `array_cat()` was selected over `array_append()` because there can be more than one string provided as input to this script, two of the same on input may result in duplicates being inserted. Still, it would make more sense to remove duplicates only from the input and concatenate that instead of deduplicating the concatenation of the input and the existing, previously deduplicated data.

Comment: @Zegarek: if it's important to keep unique elements in the array, then writing a custom function would make things easier for the UPDATE statement.

Comment: That's correct, I'm adding multiple array elements and thus using array_cat instead. The input is made by an external party and sometimes the existing user already has a couple of competition_ids.

Comment: @Panface: I would create a function to handle this. See my edit